# Laravel adds an extra slash to link

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm building my own cms with Laravel 5.1 with blade templating.

The following code:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('dashboard.menu.{menuid}.item.create', $menu->id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-block">New</a>
```

generates the correct url to my route, like this:

http://localhost:8888/D_U_site/public/dashboard/menu/1/item/create

But when i try to link to my @edit method on my controller with this code:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('dashboard.menu.{menuid}.item.edit', $menu->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
```

it generates the following url:

http://localhost:8888/D_U_site/public/dashboard/menu/1/item//edit

You guys see the difference between these two url's? Laravel adds an extra slash before edit, which is a dead link...
I couldn't find any solution on the internet. 
Does anyone have any suggestion about what i'm doing wrong?

I'd be very grateful if you guys can help me out with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: My router looks like: dashboard/menu/{menuid}/item/{item}/edit

Comment: `dashboard.menu.{menuid}.item.create`, get rid of  `{menuid}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route to edit item is probably expecting a parameter.
You are passing `$menu->id` which is empty.

If your `$menu->id` was equal to 3 then your generated url would be like:

```
http://localhost:8888/D_U_site/public/dashboard/menu/1/item/3/edit
```